# Pygame: Program seems make a loop before end

Tags: python, loops, pygame

this below is my first test of pygame but i don't understand why program start once again after the while loop before end

```
import pygame
import time

size = width, height = 640, 480

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
darkBlue = (0,0,128)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
pink = (255,200,200)

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
x=10
posx=160
posy=120
i=0
while(i<=5):
    screen.fill(pink)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,blue,[posx,posy],50)
    pygame.display.update()
    i+=1
    posx+=x
    posy+=x
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print(i)
    #outout of 'i' is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

i've also tried to include pygame.quit after the while but make a core dumped

Comment: Because if `i` is _equal_ to 5, according to the `while` condition, the loop starts over for the sixth time.

Comment: Where is this code located? Is it in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block? Is it a main module that's also getting imported as its normal name (from some other module it imports)?

Comment: the program is all there, no more. @ForceBru the problem is not the 6, the program start 2 times

Comment: please add the whole code, even if imports are obvious, it's not reproducible

Comment: Ok, there is all

Comment: how do you execute it ? from an IDE or a shell ?

Comment: The code works fine for me

Comment: Arch linux shell on GNOME, @StamKaly really? the circle do not start again from the main point before end?

Comment: Nope, the window closes when `6` is printed in the terminal.

Comment: window closes after 6 for me as well. Using ubuntu xenial.

Comment: Maybe a version bug? I use pygame 1.9.3 and python 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the file. It's possible you used a bad name and your file is imported as a module.

Also, as suggested by Blckknight in the comments, be sure to use the guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```